# C++ segmentation fault accessing "prev" pointer in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am attempting to implement an insertion sort in C++ using a doubly linked list. It partially works, but I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to insert a node into a place besides the head. I looked through other answers, but I could not find how to fix my code through them after working for hours.

```
void List::addNode(int newVal) // adds node to end of list
{
  Node *temp = new Node;
  temp ->value = newVal;
  temp ->next = NULL;
  temp ->prev = NULL;

  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = temp;
    tail = temp;
    temp = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    tail ->next = temp;
    temp -> prev = tail;
    tail = temp;
  }
}

void List::display()
{
  cout << "The list is: " << endl;
  Node *temp = head;
  while(temp != NULL)
  {
    cout << temp ->value << endl;
    temp = temp ->next;
  }
}

void List::sort()
{
  Node *current = head;
  Node *temp = head ->next;

  while(temp != NULL)
  {
    if(current ->value > temp ->value )
    {
      insertCorrect(temp);
      current = head;
      temp = head ->next;
    }
    else
    {
      current = current ->next;
      temp = temp ->next;
    }
  }
}

void List::insertCorrect(Node *temp)
{
  if(temp ->value < head ->value)     // if the compared node is lower than head
  {
    temp -> prev -> next = temp -> next; // the node before temp now points to
    temp -> next -> prev = temp -> prev; // the node after temp and vice versa

    temp ->next = head;
    temp ->prev = NULL;
    head = temp;
    cout << "after inserting correctly in the lower than head case: " << endl;
    display();
  }
  else
  {
    Node *current = head -> next;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
      if(temp->value < current ->value)
      {
        cout << "before inserting correctly: " << endl;
        display();
        temp -> prev -> next = temp -> next; // the node before temp now points to the node
        temp -> next -> prev = temp -> prev; // after temp and vice versa
        cout << "after removing the temp node from its position" << endl;

        temp ->prev = current ->prev; // temp prev is the one before current
        temp ->next = current;        // temp next is current
        current ->prev ->next = temp; // node before current points to inserted node
        current ->prev = temp;        // current has temp inserted behind it
        cout << "after inserting correctly: " << endl;
        display();
      }
      current = current ->next;
    }
  }
```

I'm sure there's a lot of sloppy stuff, I'm still somewhat new to C++. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

updated my code. I know the error is within:

```
current ->prev ->next = temp; // node before current points to inserted node
current ->prev = temp;        // current has temp inserted behind it
```

Whenever I access current ->prev, I get the Segmentation fault (core dumped). I'm not sure how to fix the pointer issue.

Edit2: I have found that current ->prev has become NULL using an if statement. I'm looking through my program, but I cannot tell why it's like this.

Comment: Problems of this kind are solved by stepping through the code with a debugger and watching the variable values carefully for unexpected behavior, then backwards checking the logic at the point the values became unexpected. A debugger also provides a stack trace of the code location generating the fault.

Comment: `display()`, `sort()`, and `insertCorrect()` are all leaking memory. Get rid of the `new Node` calls in them, the calls don't belong there. Also, `sort()` and `insertCorrect()` do not account for an empty list (`display()` does, though)

Comment: Have you tried any debugging to try and narrow it down? Looking through other answers will just tell you basically what you may already know: you've likely got a bad pointer somewhere.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated my code, I removed the creation of new nodes. for now i'm not concerned with an empty list. I still just have the issue of the bad pointer when inserting.

Comment: @lurker @ uneven_mark I haven't using an actual debugger (don't know how) but I edited my code to show the exact block I'm having issues with. I'm not sure why exactly this issue is there or how to fix it from here though.

Comment: First, please clean up your example -- you have multiple definitions of your functions. Second, you should come up with a [mcve]. A key point would be determining a minimal set of values that you can insert into your list and reproduce the crash. Try to remove as many List operations as possible. Think "simple". *(Also, since you've identified the problem as a null `prev` link, maybe output a diagnostic with each line that sets a `prev` link.)*